# Options other than using Date.parse()

Tags: javascript, date, parsing, sapui5

Here is what I need to do :

I have a  ISO 8601 format dateString `dateString = "2016-09-30T04:00:00.000+0000"`
 which I need to parse and produce a readable date "`September 30, 2016`"

Here is my formatter `sap.ui.core.format.DateFormat`that does this for me.

```
return dateFormatter.format(new Date(dateString));
```

Trouble is, According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse),

> It is not recommended to use Date.parse as until ES5, parsing of
>   strings was entirely implementation dependent. There are still many
>   differences in how different hosts parse date strings, therefore date
>   strings should be manually parsed (a library can help if many
>   different formats are to be accommodated).
>
> - Direct call: `Date.parse(dateString)`
> - Implicit call: `new Date(dateString)`

So `Date.parse()` is called anyway with my formatter.

Are there any better practices to do such manual parsing as recommended by MDN?
Is there any SAPUI5 way to achieve this?

Comment: ES5, I would think there are very few people on ES3, and if there were on ES3, then I doubt SAPUI5 would work :), so I'd say your fine to use parse.  If not there is also moment.js you could use.

Comment: `Date.parse` is *supported* from ES5, but the ways it's implemented in engines is still not consistent, hence why you should do the date parsing yourself.

Comment: @adeneo, that date looks like a perfectly formed ISO date, if you know of any browsers that can't decode that, I'd be interested.

Comment: The dateString is of the ISO 8601 format

Comment: ISO 8601 will work just fine with the Date constructor, as it's the standard used by javascript for ISO dates, I'm commenting on the use of `Date.parse` in general. Note that the documentation actually says *"A string representing an RFC2822 or ISO 8601 date (other formats may be used, but results may be unexpected)."*, it's the other formats parts where it's recommended to not use `Date.parse`

Comment: @adeneo—I don't trust Date to parse strings at all. Parsing ISO 8601 per the OP is two lines of code, which delivers compatibility with every implementation ever. Two more lines if time zone offset other than Z is required.  There are many mobile and other device browsers that aren't up speed with the latest ECMA-262. I wouldn't trust RFC 2822 either, it's not part of the standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parsing ISO dates should be consistent in most engines, but there's no guarantee, the proper way to define a Date object would always be to pass the integer arguments as follows

```
new Date(year, month[, day[, hour[, minutes[, seconds[, milliseconds]]]]]);
```

but seeing as you want a string containing months etc. back, and not an object, the most consistent way to do this would be to simply parse the dates yourself

```js
var dateString = "2016-09-30T04:00:00.000+0000";

var months = [
  '', 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April',
  'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September',
  'October', 'November', 'December'
];

var parts  = dateString.split(/[-T:.]/);
var parsed = months[+parts[1]] + ' ' + parts[2] + ', ' + parts[0];

document.body.innerHTML = parsed; // September 30, 2016
```

Comment: After much discussion, trial and error - the SAPUI5 way of solving this would be to use [sap.ui.model.type.DateTime](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.type.DateTime.html) or [sap.ui.model.type.Date](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.type.Date.html) if you don't have too much customization to do with displaying dates. Using this would however base the styling of the dates based on locale information or the local machine's date time.